# How to Separate and automatically add missing faces?

Tags: faces

I'm attempting to separate out pieces of my model and would like to automate adding faces to the "previously attached" holes. How can I do this?

Alternative: Is there a better way that "separate"?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate with Shift+D before separating

Answer (score 2):

it's not really automated but you could use the "fill holes" clean-up tool.

1. separate the meshes
2. in edit mode, select all vertices
3. `Mesh ‣ Clean up ‣ Fill Holes`
4. repeat steps 2 and 3 for all separated meshes

Comment: Very simple and perfect solution. Thanks. Should be marked as an answer though!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to separate faces but keep them in the original model:

1. select faces and press **P** to separate faces (just as you did)

[image: one]

2. while you are in **Edit Mode**, press **Ctrl+Z**

[image: two]

3. in **Object Mode** you will have the separated faces and the missing ones attached to the object too (you will have two objects in the outliner, of course)

[image: three]

Answer (score 0):

A method, all in edit mode on a single object...

[image]

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> select radial edge-ring, and then Select header menu > Select Loops > Edge Loops
- <kbd>V</kbd> rip all the selected edges
- Mesh header menu > Clean Up > Fill Holes

Answer (score 0):

The following helped me fill holes or redraw walls.

Select the object

*Modeling -> Mesh -> Clean Up -> Fill Holes*

[image: Fill Holes]